# How to add Save file Dialog Box using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, savefiledialog, notepad

I need to implement something similar to **Notepads'** save option. Assuming I have a button placed next to a `RichTextBox`, what I want is, when this button is clicked, a Dialogue box will open up, which will look similar to the one that appears when **Save As** is clicked. I would like to save the content of the RichTextBox in text format, by entering the name of file in the **Save Dialogue** box.

Comment: Hmm, how did you know to use the [savefiledialog] tag?  Fake question?

Comment: @Hans: I was typing out savefile and then I was suggested this tag. Prior to the answers below, I though this tag literally meant "Dialogue to Save file". That is, I didn't know it was name of a Control.

Comment: Well, credit to SO to give you the answer before you post it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
private void Save_As_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SaveFileDialog _SD = new SaveFileDialog(); 
  _SD.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt|Show All Files (*.*)|*.*";
  _SD.FileName = "Untitled"; 
  _SD.Title = "Save As";
  if (__SD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
   RTBox1.SaveFile(__SD.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed post which clarifies more on file types and Title. What about adding a default file name, how to do that?

Comment: Only add over the if block this code `_SD.FileName = "Untitled";`

Answer (score 7):

For **WPF** you should use this [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog.aspx).

```
var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "Rich Text File (*.rtf)|*.rtf|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
dialog.FileName = "Filename.rtf"; //set initial filename
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    using (var stream = dialog.OpenFile())
    {
       var range = new TextRange(myRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
                                 myRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
       range.Save(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
}
```

Comment: what about saving the content. The XAML tag will possibly open up a Dialog Box, but how is the content supposed to get save?

Comment: @Sam, OpenFile requires less permissions. Also isn't FileOutputStream java??

Comment: i use FileOutputStream in C# 2005.Used like this.. java.io.OutputStream ostream = new java.io.FileOutputStream(new java.io.File(FileName));
WorkBook.write(ostream);
ostream.close();

Answer (score 2):

This works for text files and was tested in `WPF`.

```
var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*"; 
dialog.FileName = "Filename.txt"; 
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{                
    File.WriteAllText(dialog.FileName, MyTextBox.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*misread the question - Ray's answer is valid for OP*

This works only in Windows Forms.

You should take a look at the SaveFileDialog class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx

And save the file using something like this (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile(v=vs.80).aspx)):

```
rtf.SaveFile(dialog.FileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. What about the content of the file which is to come from RichTextBox. How is that content going to be saved to the corresponding file?

Comment: Added some more info on saving the file from the RTF.

Comment: Replace the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace with `Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog` and I think you're good to go.

Comment: RichTextBox doesn't have a SaveFile in WPF

Comment: Damn, I missed that one. You're right. Your answer solves the OP's question perfectly, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
SaveFileDialog sfDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
sfDialog.ShowDialog();
OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(new File(sfDialog.FileName));
WorkBook.write(ostream);
ostream.close();
```

Comment: Does FileOutputStream exist in .net?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `SaveFileDialog` component which you can use, read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984409%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to find out how it works and a working sample.